# Cakephp 2.x - hide/show a combobox

Tags: javascript, cakephp, combobox, hide, show

I try to hide/show a combobox, I have 2 combobox and I want the second to be hidden until the first change.

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('combobox1'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('combobox2'); ?>
```

So I think I need to do something like :

`$this->Js->get('#idcombobox2')->effect('hide');` to hide the combobox when the page just load.

And something like :

`$this->Js->get('#idcombo1')->event('change', $this->Js->get('#idcombobox2')->effect('show'));` cause if the first change I want to show the second.

but this doesn't work.

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

are you including jquery or other framework in the view?

```
echo $this->Html->script('//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js');
```

and in case you're outputting it into the `<head>` with `array('inline' => false)`, make sure to specify the script location in the layout:

```
echo $scripts_for_layout;
```

remember you also need to output the buffer in the view:

```
echo $this->Js->writeBuffer();
```

**edit:** the code that actually worked for me:

```
$event = $this->Js->get('#combo2')->effect('show');
$this->Js->get('#combo1')->event('change', $event);
```

**edit 2:** somehow i just got to hide the combo2 using a `scriptBlock`. so the whole code would go like this

```
$hide = $this->Js->get('#combo2')->effect('hide');
echo $this->Html->scriptBlock($this->Js->domReady($hide));
$show = $this->Js->get('#combo2')->effect('show');
$this->Js->get('#combo1')->event('change', $show);
echo $this->Js->writeBuffer(array('inline' => false));
```